# Maven Deploy to Nexus Fails When Deploying Artifact with Classifier

Tags: maven, nexus

All,

I have a Spring Boot Application which needs to be deployed to Nexus as both a library and an executable jar. Spring provides a way to have both using the following bit of code in the POM file.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

This produces the following two JARs.

```
(a) target/[artifact]-[version].jar
(b) target/[artifact]-[version]-exec.jar
```

Previous to adding the code to the POM, I am able to deploy artifact `(a)` to Nexus without issue. However, once I add the code, I get the following exception.

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project [artifact-id]: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact [group-id]:[artifact-id]:jar:exec:[version]-[iteration] in nexus.ftc.lab ([nexus-url])
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact [group-id]:[artifact-id]:jar:exec:[version]-[iteration] in nexus.ftc.lab ([nexus-url])
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject(DeployMojo.java:284)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:169)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
  ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact [group-id]:[artifact-id]:jar:exec:[version]-[iteration] in nexus.ftc.lab ([nexus-url])
  at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject(DeployMojo.java:279)
  ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact [group-id]:[artifact-id]:jar:exec:[version]-[iteration] in nexus.ftc.lab ([nexus-url])
  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:317)
  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
  at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
  ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact [group-id]:[artifact-id]:jar:exec:[version]-[iteration] in nexus.ftc.lab ([nexus-url])
  at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:893)
  at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
  at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$PutTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:743)
  at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.put(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:345)
  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:311)
  ... 28 more
```

To add to the intrigue. I tried building another JAR using more standard code. When I deploy using this, it works fine.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
         <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <classifier>client</classifier>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

One more update, when I try the below, it fails with the same exception.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                 <shadedClassifierName>fat</shadedClassifierName>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>

  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What version of Nexus are you using? It's worked for me in a Nexus 2.14.

Comment: Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14.4-03

Comment: You could try to reproduce the problem as I did. I just ran a docker container of [Nexus](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus/). Then I followed this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) to create a Spring Boot Application, added the classifier and deployed. It worked without problems. I took 20 minutes to create this POC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by request filtering limits in an IIS proxy.

By default, the maximum allowed content length was 30 MB. This was blocking my post of a ~90 MB jar file. Increasing the limit to 512 MB fixed the problem.